# Magento 2: Upgrading Magento 2 version from v2.1.5 to v2.1.17

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Does anyone upgrade **Magento 2** version from `v2.1.5 to 2.1.17` ?

Since Magento `Releases` any `patches` based on **v2.3.x**, **v2.2.x** and **v2.1.x**, I guess minor version might have many differences and dependencies.

I would like to here from someone who already upgraded minor version.

**Thank you in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading the same version from 2.1.5 to 2.1.17, then it is fine cause same version chain don't have codebase drastic changes so it won't affect on your current code but still do backup your current data and after upgrade it.

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded upgraded from Magento 2.1.9 to 2.1.12. I faced only a single issue with setup version for a core module. I think so it was in Tax module. So once I changed the setup version manually and did the upgrade everything was working fine then. Similarly I have also upgrade from Magento 2.1.8 to 2.2.3 and I didn't face any issues with upgradation.